# how to call a view function in the template dynamically in Django

Tags: python, django

I am implementing a weather app in Django using `openweathermap` API. I have a form in my HTML and a action in it to trigger the method in my view. It works fine, but the problem is I have to trigger the action with a button in my form everytime I want the weather, but I want to get the weather dynamically in such a way that it generates the weather every 3 hrs. I thought of doing it with timmer but I don't know whether its the proper approach if any know of a good way to implement it please enlighten me.

I want an app which generates weather dynamically without triggering any action. If my query is not understandable or want more information please do ask, I bad at put my query in words.

Comment: Go through http://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 1):

I'd normally use one of the following 2 options:

1. Implement a Django command which you can call from a cronjob
2. Use a Python package called Celery in combination with RabbitMQ or Redis and call your command using Celery's periodic task functionality.

Both methods will allow you to run the code every 3 hours.

You'd probably take your code which calls up the weather API and stores it inside DB, out of the view and place it inside your Django command. Your view will then simply serve data obtained by your periodic task.

I hope that helps!